# Value is getting multiply by 100 when using percentage on value axis bar chart JfreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using JfreeChart 1.0.15 library.
I want to show percentage score of the college and branches, so I used `setNumberFormatOverride()` method

```
final NumberAxis valueAxis = new NumberAxis("Percentage Score");
valueAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(NumberFormat.getPercentInstance());
```

It is showing me the `%` sign on the `Y-axis` but all the values are getting multiplied by 100.

[image: Actual output]

See the `Y-axis` values. Label values on the bars are correct.

If I divide each value by 100 then `Y-axis` values are correct (e.g. 15%,19%,25%,27%) but label values are displaying wrong (e.g. 0.15,0.19,0.25,0.27).

Below code also won't give the desired output

```
DecimalFormat pctFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.0%");
valueAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(pctFormat);
```

I tried different solutions from

- http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=30345
- http://www.infocaptor.com/dashboard/number-and-percent-format-for-charts-bar-line-etc
- http://jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=24268
- http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13797&sid=8459981dcbb26de2f55be5c4da97e51a

none of them worked.
If you need more information let me know.

Comment: What format are your numbers in before? What do you mean by _label values are displaying wrong_? Can you give us some code?

Comment: @Keppil : `label values are displaying wrong` means 0.19, 0.27 etc where as on the Y-axis values are 19%,27% etc

Comment: Well, `0.19` is the same as `19%`, so it sounds like what you are trying to do is use the `%` in a non-standard way.

Comment: @Keppil : Yes. You are right, so how can I show the label values from 0.19 to 19%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [@Keppil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1343161/keppil). I managed to solve from your [*valuable* comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423655/value-is-getting-multiply-by-100-when-using-percentage-on-value-axis-bar-chart-j#comment32320888_21423655)

I was using below code to set label

```
barPlot.getRenderer().setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator());
barPlot.getRenderer().setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
```

The mistake was invoking default constructor `StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator()`.
See question labels are not in percent `%` format.

I solved by passing `NumberFormat` instance `pctFormat` to the parameterized constructor [StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator(java.lang.String labelFormat, java.text.NumberFormat formatter)](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator.html#StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.NumberFormat%29)

```
barPlot.getRenderer().setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator("{2}",pctFormat));
barPlot.getRenderer().setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
```

[image: Correct output]

Now format has been applied to the labels also.

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the source for `NumberFormat` you'll see that `NumberFormat#getPercentInstance()` actually returns a `DecimalFormat` instance. Although it's not immediately obvious from the source what format string that instance uses it's safe to assume it contains a `%`.

According to the `DecimalFormat` [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) section titled *Special Pattern Characters*, a `%` in a format string means `Multiply by 100 and show as percentage`. Luckily `NumberFormat` provides a `setMultiplier()` method, so you can do this to fix your issue:

```
DecimalFormat pctFormat = new DecimalFormat("##.0%");
pctFormat.setMultiplier(1);
valueAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(pctFormat);
```

I believe you can also enquote the `%`, like this:

```
DecimalFormat pctFormat = new DecimalFormat("##.0'%'");
valueAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(pctFormat);
```

Comment: +1 and Thanks for Java docs reference. Now, this multiply by 100 problem solved. I also tried some from above Keppil comments. Another way is to set the label and the percentage format.